# Can I reply my own mails with PHPMailer, that's possible?

Tags: phpmailer

I need a information about PHPMailer about replying my own mails.
I need send a empty mail(subject, body), and when the first mail sent second mail need sending with replying first mail.
That's possible ?

I tried but never can repyling my own mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but PHPMailer won't do this for you. You will need to do it by getting and setting appropriate headers, in particular the `Message-ID` header that identifies each message, and the `In-Reply-To` and `References` headers which are used to track whether something is a reply. Probably the best way to see these working is to simulate it using your regular email client - Outlook, Gmail, Apple Mail – all of which will set those headers correctly.